# Use JSON array in SQL server instead of traditional relational database, each value in 1 row

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

I have saved the answer values in a table in rows, 1 answer 1 row, 5 rows in this example.
If I migrate it to JSON it will be 2 rows(JSON)

**Table**

| Id | Optionsid | Pid | Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | null |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | null |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | null |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | null |

I want to calculate how many answers(pid) for each **Optionsid** with

```
SELECT COUNT(pid)AS Counted, OptionsId
FROM  Answer GROUP BY [Column], OptionsId
```

**Table Results**

| Counted | Optionsid |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

I have run thus query and saved it in a new table

```
select * from Answer  for Json Auto
```

**Json Table**  I added {"answer":} to the Json

| id | pid | json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | {"Answer":[{"Id":1,"Optionsid":2,"Pid":1}]} |
| 2 | 2 | {"Answer":[{"Id":2,"Optionsid":1,"Pid":2},{"Id":2,"Optionsid":1,"Pid":2},{"Id":3,"Optionsid":2,"Pid":2},{"Id":4,"Optionsid":3,"Pid":2}]} |

I want to get the same result from **Json Table** as the **Table result** above, but I can get it to work
This Query only take the first[0] in the array, i want a query who take all values in the array.
Can someone help me with this query?

```
  Select Count(Json_value ([json], '$.Answer[0].Pid')) as Counted,
  Json_value ([json], '$.Answer[0].Optionsid') as OptionsId
  from [PidJson]
  group by Json_value ([json],'$.Answer[0].Column'),Json_value 
  ([json],'$.Answer[0].Optionsid')
```

Here is a fiddle if you want to see

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0a2df33717a3917bae699ea3983b70b4

Comment: FYI, Although fiddles are helpful they shouldn't be *required* for us to be able understand the question. Your DDL, DML and attempt(s) should also be included in the question itself. Otherwise if the fiddle can't be viewed, your question is far from helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have tried to make it more clear, if its not tell me

Comment: What actual result do you want?

Comment: I want the Table Results from Json Table

Comment: I have edited the questions again
I want to correct this last query in the question "Select Count(Json_value ([json]..."

Comment: Perhaps you have an XY problem?

Comment: You're still not showing what result you want, only the broken code you have already. Please show that as a formatted table. It's unclear if you want the whole array broken out into rows, or if you want it aggregated in some way. It's also unclear what `Answer` has to do with the question, whether you want to regenerate the JSON or whether you want to use the existing `PidJson` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
SELECT Count(JsonData.Pid)  as Counted,  
JsonData.Optionsid
FROM PidJson AS RelationsTab
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (RelationsTab.json, 
N'$.Answer') 
WITH (
    Pid VARCHAR(200) N'$.Pid',
    Optionsid VARCHAR(200) N'$.Optionsid',
    ColumnValue INT N'$.Column'
   ) AS JsonData
Group by JsonData.ColumnValue, JsonData.Optionsid
```

Thanks for your time and that you "force" me to clearify my question and I find the solution